# Cast a substring catched by a regex to an integer and used it as an function argument in VB.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net, type-conversion

I've got a string such as :

```
Dim initialString As String = "Some text here is f(42,foo,bar) and maybe some other here."
```

And want to replace the "f(42,foo,bar)" part to the evaluation of a function with following prototype :

```
    Function myLittleFunction(ByVal number As Integer, ByVal string0 As String = "NA0", ByVal string1 As String = "NA1")
```

Witch I did with this regex :

```
finalString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(initialString, "f\((\d+),([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+),([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)\)", myLittleFunction(Convert.ToUInt32("${1}"), "$2", "$3"))
```

But that's not working because Convert.ToUInt32("${1}") fails. If a replace it by any integer by hand and run the code, I've got the correct evaluation and replacement in my string.

How can I correctly cast "$1" to appropriate integer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String replacement pattern cannot be interpolated for use as variables to a method.

You may use a [match evaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Dim rx = New Regex("f\((\d+),([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+),([a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+)\)")
Dim result = rx.Replace(s, New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
         Return myLittleFunction(Convert.ToUInt32(m.Groups(1).Value), m.Groups(2).Value, m.Groups(3).Value)
     End Function))
```

The `m` is a `Match` object, the one that is found by the `Regex.Replace` method. You may access all the groups captured with the regex using `m.Groups(N).Value`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very interesting and powerful tool. And thanks for the \s correction ;)